# Cannot invoke 'decodeResponse' with an argument list of type '(modelType: Decodable, data: Data)'

Tags: swift

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class CustomRequest {

  var sendingRequest: Codable;
  let url: URL
  var request: URLRequest;
  var device: UIDevice
  var responseMapper: Decodable

  init(request: Codable, url: String, mapper: Decodable){
      self.sendingRequest = request
      self.responseMapper = mapper;
      self.url = URL(string: url)!
      self.request = URLRequest(url: self.url)
      self.device = UIDevice.current
  }

  func send(){
      URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: self.request) {data, response, error in
          guard error == nil else {return print("NETWORK ERROR")}
          self.decodeResponse(modelType: self.responseMapper.self, data:data!)
      }
  }

  func decodeResponse<T>(modelType: T.Type, data: Data) where T:Decodable {
      JSONDecoder().decode(modelType, from: data)
  }
}
```

What I', doing wrong in this case? Please help me with this question. 
I started learning swift quite recently and ran into such a problem.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of `responseMapper` must be a concrete type. It cannot be a protocol.

A possible solution is a generic type constrained to `Decodable`.

And you have to add a completion handler for the data task

```
class CustomRequest<T : Decodable> {

    var sendingRequest: Codable;
    let url: URL
    var request: URLRequest;
    var device: UIDevice
    var responseMapper: T

    init(request: Codable, url: String, mapper: T){
        self.sendingRequest = request
        self.responseMapper = mapper;
        self.url = URL(string: url)!
        self.request = URLRequest(url: self.url)
        self.device = UIDevice.current
    }

    func send(completion: @escaping (Result<T,Error>) -> Void) {
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: self.request) { data, response, error in
            guard error == nil else { completion(.failure(error!)); return }
            completion(Result { try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data!) })
        }
    }
}
```